# How to extend layers to fit the timeline in AE

Tags: adobe-after-effects

I am making a composition in After Effects with an illustrator file which has 10 layers. All 10 layers are animated either through keyframe or effects.

The composition was initially for 2 seconds. Now I want to change the composition timing either by increasing or decreasing to see how the overall comp looks like. Now whenever I do that, I need to manually  increase or decrease the layers one by one to fill the extended or decreased new timeline.

Is there a clever way to do all of them at once ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  Video Editing questions are [off-topic here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).  For future reference, these should be posted on Video Production Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I realised just after posting it.

Select all layers-> Control+Shift-> extend to fit the timeline all at once.